# How to align an equation horizontally in qtree, centering one character of my equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, qtree

I have the following code for my qtree:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{qtree}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.$\neg\left(\varphi\sqcup\psi\right)\circ \neg\varphi\sqcup\psi$ 
        [.$\circ \left(\varphi \sqcup \psi \right)$ {$\varphi, \psi \circ$} 
          {$\circ \varphi,\psi$} ] ]
\hfill
\textbf{(8.2.1)}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to center around the `\circ` character, so that the line in my tree starts at the `\circ` in my equation `$\neg\left(\varphi\sqcup\psi\right)\circ \neg\varphi\sqcup\psi$`, and ends at the `\circ` in `$\circ \left(\varphi \sqcup \psi \right)$`. I've tried `\hspace{}` but setting the right values to get the equations aligned correctly is *horribly* tedious.

I want to do either of the following two things:

Simply adjust the lining in my qtree so that they do not started centered, but instead at the `\circ`.

Or the more preferred method: compensate for the normal way of drawing lines by aligning my equation horizontally.

Does LaTeX or `qtree` offer a command to automatically align horizontally around one such character in my equation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this approach, I lapped all the components except the `\circ`, so that the tree would center on that symbol.  I used an `\hfill` on both left and right so as to center the `\circ` horizontally on the line.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\hfill\Tree [.$\llap{$\neg\left(\varphi\sqcup\psi\right)$}\circ \rlap{$\neg\varphi\sqcup\psi$}$ 
        [.$\circ \rlap{$\left(\varphi \sqcup \psi \right)$}$ {$\llap{$\varphi, \psi$} \circ$} 
          {$\circ\rlap{$\varphi,\psi$}$} ] ]
\hfill
\textbf{(8.2.1)}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can quickly and easily automate the process by creating a macro

```
\newcommand\ccen[2]{\llap{$#1$}$\circ$\rlap{$#2$}}
```

that is provided the contents to the left and right of the `\circ`.  Its usage would be as follows:

```
\hfill\Tree [.\ccen{\neg\left(\varphi\sqcup\psi\right)}{\neg\varphi\sqcup\psi} 
        [.\ccen{}{\left(\varphi \sqcup \psi \right)} {\ccen{\varphi, \psi}{}} 
          {\ccen{}{\varphi,\psi}} ] ]
\hfill
\textbf{(8.2.1)}
```

If one would like space around the `\circ`, then this definition would do:

```
\newcommand\ccen[2]{\llap{$#1$}${}\mathrel{\circ}{}$\rlap{$#2$}}
```

which would produce this result:

[image]

Comment: Yep, pretty much like this, though I'm trying to avoid the `\hspace` because I have to enter thousands of these formulas and I'd like a standardized method to implement this visual style.

Comment: @Euryris If you changed my `\hspace*{4ex}` to `\hfill`, then the trees will all be centered.  Is that OK?

Comment: Will this solution produce the same results regardless of how long/big the tree is? If so, then that'll suffice. Thank you. EDIT: Sorry, checked it. Yep, this seems to be exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Euryris I do not work with tree's to know the answer to your question.  But even I can see that there could very easily be problems with more depth to the tree (since the lapping takes up zero horizontal space).